# IndexOutOfBoundsException in Eclipse EGit using "Team->Switch To"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

When I right click my project and select "Team->Switch To", the menu doesn't list any of my branches, it's empty except for the "New Branch..." option.

I checked the Eclipse error log and it's throwing this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.wrap(ByteBuffer.java:371)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.RawParseUtils.decodeNoFallback(RawParseUtils.java:942)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.RawParseUtils.decode(RawParseUtils.java:909)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.RawParseUtils.decode(RawParseUtils.java:868)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.util.RawParseUtils.parsePersonIdentOnly(RawParseUtils.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ReflogEntryImp.<init>(ReflogEntryImpl.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ReflogReaderImpl.getReverseEntries(ReflogReaderImpl.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.internal.storage.file.ReflogReaderImpl.getReverseEntries(ReflogReaderImpl.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.SwitchToMenu.createDynamicMenu(SwitchToMenu.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.actions.SwitchToMenu.fill(SwitchToMenu.java:111)
    ...
```

Any clues as to what's wrong or why this is happening?

I'm running:

- Eclipse 4.4.2.M20150204-1700
- CentOS 6.7
- Java 1.7.0_85

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that something goes wrong while decoding the author of a commit. Can you scan the repository to see if there is a reflog entry whose author/committer does not follow the pattern 'author <name@host.com>'? Either (a part of) the reflog is corrupt or you encountered a bug in EGit or JGit.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I had been pulling my hair out over this - you were right about the author settings. I fixed them and now the menu is showing up correctly. If you want to make it an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stacktrace suggests that something goes wrong while decoding the author of a commit. Possibly the reflog contains an entry whose author or committer does not follow the pattern `author <name@host.com>`.

Not sure if it is legal in Git to have author names that do not follow the above pattern. If however, EGit/JGit allows to store them in the system it shouldn't complain while retrieving them again.

Hence I think it might be worth filing an [EGit bugzilla](https://eclipse.org/egit/support/) to have the maintainers verify that this is desired behavior.